# I am not getting any output when I try to run the .class File that was created from my .java file in terminal. The code is compiling just not printing

Tags: java, terminal

[This is what I have done in the terminal. I have tried compiling the .java file and it compiles fine because it is creating a .class file I am unsure as to why the .class file is not being executed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJqWN.png)

Comment: Don't post code or [error as screenshot](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). In the end it's just a text.

Comment: We also need to see the contents of the `HelloWorld.java` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class name in your code, is a different name from your file name,
for example if I am making a new file with the name HelloWorld.java,
my code should be like this

```java
class HelloWorld
{
//your code
}
```

it shouldn't have a different class name. even the case should be correct.

To fix your problem, just open your HelloWorld.java file, and change the class name from `Main` to `HelloWorld` it will work!!

All the best learning java! its a great language..

Comment: That about packages?  You are assuming that the OP hasn't used a `package` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `java file` name and `java class` name the same exact name and then see. IF not share you java code.

Answer (score -1):

Rename the class as HelloWorld instead of Main it will work fine.